# Pagination in Nodejs (ORM Sequelize) from React-Native App

Tags: node.js, react-native, sequelize.js

Sorry if my title is not descriptive. I have a react native app and nodejs backend with sequelize as my ORM.

Initially everything was working and i was getting all my posts from my backend and viewing them in my frontend. I also had a search bar for users to search for the title of any posts and the post will appear.

after days of research and asking questions, i got told that it is not best practise to view all the posts together because this means that all the posts will be load to the user and if the user does not scroll down that will be a waste.

I got recommended that i should implement pagination and filtering the title in my backend and then use them in my frontend. since posts will be divided into pages and the user is required to scroll to load the next set of posts and so on. And for the filter, it will filter the entire database and view the posts that have the searched word or phrase in its title.

I have been trying for the past couple of days to do so, but it is not working with me at all.

when i scroll down, the next page does not get rendered and i get an error in my backend with the following:

```
(node:22371) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: column "nan" does not 
exist
```

When i load the app in my backend the console.log(page) prints 0, which is correct but when i scroll down to view the next page the console.log(page) prints undefined then throws the error above.

Here is my backend code:

```
router.get("/",
async (req, res) => {
let filter = {};
let { q } = req.query;
if (q) {
filter = {
  where: {
    title: {
      [Op.like]: `${q}%`,
    },
  },
 };
}

const getPagination = (page) => {
const limit = 10;
const offset = page ? page * limit : 0;

return { limit, offset };
};

const { page } = req.query;
const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page);

console.log(page)

const posts = await Post.findAll({
limit,offset,
filter,
order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
```

Here is my React Native Code:

```
const getPosts = (page) => client.get(`/posts?page=${page}`);
```

My custom hook:

```
export default useApi = (apiFunc) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const request = async (...args) => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await apiFunc(...args);
setLoading(false);

setError(!response.ok);
setData(response.data);
return response;
};

return { request, data, error, loading };
};
```

My Posts Screen:

```
const { data: posts, error, loading, request: loadPosts } = useApi(getPosts);

const[page,setPage]=useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
loadPosts(page);
}, [page]);

const handleLoadMore = ()=>{
setPage(page+1);
}

 let posts = posts.filter((post) => {
 return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
 });

const updateSearch = (e) => {
setSearch(e);
};

return(

<TextInput onChangeText={updateSearch}/> 
// this is how i was implementing the search in frontend but now i want implement from 
backend//

 <FlatList
      data={posts} // to have all the data
      keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Card
          title={item.title}
          subTitle={item.subtitle}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.PostDetails, item)}
        />
      )}
      bounces={false}
      onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.001}
    />
)
```

If anyone can help me fix the the load more handler and add filtering to my Flatlist from backend would be really appreciative. Thank you in advance.

Update 1

I only have 2 pages of posts, page 0 and page 1. When i load the app page 0 gets rendered but when i scroll down to load more posts i get an empty screen which means it skipped page 1 and went to the page after.

Update 2

In my flatlist i added the following and now when i scroll down only the second page gets rendered how do i adjust my code so that the second page gets added to the first page?

```
initialNumToRender={10}
      onMomentumScrollBegin = {() => 
{onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum}}
      onEndReached = {() => {
      if (!onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
      loadPosts(page+1)    // LOAD MORE DATA
       setonEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum(true);
      }
      }
      }
```

Comment: There is no 'filter' option in Sequelize, use "where" instead. await Post.findAndCountAll({limit, offset, ...filter, ...})

Comment: @Mr. i created the filter function myself and added it, you will find it above the findAll